# Find all permutations of a set of numbers and operators

Tags: javascript, recursion, permutation

I was given a code challenge to do that was related to recursion and was unable to complete it.  My experience with these types of questions is very slim and this one just stumped me.  Could any of you help me out just for my own education, as I've already failed the challenge?

The description:

Given a string of numbers and operators, print out all the different ways you can add parentheses to force the order of operations to be explicit, and the result for running the operations in that order.

Assume:
No weird inputs, everything is separated by one space.
Supported operators are +, *, -, = (for the = operator, if the values are the same return 1, otherwise return 0)
Print your results sorted numerically
Don't worry about the input expression size being too large
Your code should be written in javascript
Don't use eval or external libraries

Example:

```
node test.js "2 - 1 - 1"
((2-1)-1) = 0
(2-(1-1)) = 2

node test.js "2 * 3 - 4 * 5";
(2*(3-(4*5))) = -34
((2*3)-(4*5)) = -14
((2*(3-4))*5) = -10
(2*((3-4)*5)) = -10
(((2*3)-4)*5) = 10

node test.js "2 + 2 = 2"
((2+2)=2) = 0
(2+(2=2)) = 3
```

This is where I'm at so far.  I'm far from getting the right output, but I feel like the logic is starting to get there.  I've adapted this code from a similar, but different question.

```
var args = process.argv.slice(2)[0].split(" "),
    numberOfOperators = 0;

args.forEach(function(val, index, array) {
  if (isNaN(val)) {
    ++numberOfOperators;
  }
});

args = args.join("");


var recurse = function(openParenCount, closeParenCount, input, pointer) {
  if (openParenCount === 0 && closeParenCount === 0) {
    console.log(input + "\n");
  }
  if (openParenCount > 0) {
    input = input.slice(0, pointer) + "(" + input.slice(pointer, input.length);
    recurse(openParenCount - 1, closeParenCount + 1, input, pointer+1);
  }

  if (closeParenCount > 0) {
    input = input.slice(0, pointer+openParenCount+3) + ")" + input.slice(pointer+openParenCount+3, input.length+1);
    recurse(openParenCount, closeParenCount - 1, input, pointer+3);
  }
}

recurse(numberOfOperators, 0, args, 0);
```

Comment: have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Please post the code you tried, and explain what went wrong. We're not going to write this for you from the scratch.

Comment: I've added what I've written so far.  I can't seem to nail down the portion of the array to pass as the third argument to the recurse() function.

Answer (score 1):

a little hint:

```
var AP = [];
var input = process.argv.slice(2)[0];
var args = input.replace(/\s+/g, "").split(/([^\d\.]+)/g);

recurse(args, []).forEach(function(v){ console.log(v); });
function recurse(arr, into){
    if(arr.length === 1){
        into.push(arr[0]);
    }else{
        for(var i=0, j=arr.length-2; i<j; i+=2){
            recurse(
                AP.concat(
                    arr.slice(0, i),
                    "(" + arr.slice(i, i+3).join(" ") + ")",
                    arr.slice(i+3)
                ),
                into
            )   
        }
    }
    return into
}
```

This Implementation still has a few "bugs", and these by intent; I'm not going to do your "homework".

If you have more than 2 operators in your Equasion, the result will contain duplicates, 2nd It is not sorted, and since it is just splitting and concatenating strings, it can't compute any result.

But it shows you a way how you can implement the recursion.